# VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, apache

I have been facing this error quite a long time, My production environment is running Apache 2.4 and php7 on a windows 2008 R2 enterprise platform.

My error log is full of these lines
**VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.
VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address**

After some time it leads to a 500 error, and later I have to restart the server it works fine only for some time.

Please help me in resolving these issues I have tried to update the memory from php and wordpress end but still no help

Comment: May be helpful:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/40033719/4248328

Comment: I have checked all the plugins and i use only limited plugins it is not because of plugin. pls help me in finding the root cause for this issue i hav checked in local setup also no memory issues in the local environment

Comment: We have the same issue, and not really sure how to fix. Do you end up solving the issue?

Comment: I suffered this when upgrading XAMPP, so am assuming it's going from PHP 5 to 7. But I am at a loss to how to fix it and experience these exact symptoms daily.

Answer (score 2):

Your project may not be setup on the *appropriate architecture*.

Is your PHP 32 bit? Check the `PHP_INT_SIZE` constant to find out.

```
print_r(PHP_INT_SIZE); # 4 == 32bit // 8 == 64bit
```

Windows Server 2008 R2 is an x64 operating system, so an x86 version of Apache +/- x86 PHP could be capping the memory you may have installed on your machine and are trying to allocate. You won't be able to allocate more than 2G on on x86 version.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error if I do

```
composer update
```

It worked for me when I tried

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and this command fixed issue for me on localhost

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar"
```

then do `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

Just Update latest version of composer

https://getcomposer.org/download/

otherwise do below steps

This setting only in Local machine(commands)

To Check PHP Memory

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"
```

output:

```
128M
```

To Know PHP path

```
php --ini
```

output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp72\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)    
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Just Update your memory limit

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=512M
```

For Unlimit memory Access

```
memory_limit=-1
```

or
simply run for windows

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update
```

Note:
I recommend must download latest composer version

**composer -v**

Answer (score 0):

Updating php.ini file working for me.
If you are using a Windows machine, you can try to increase the Memory Limit to 2 Gigabytes, as Laravel suggests, in your php.ini.
On XAMPP it is located at C:\xampp\php\php.ini

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 2G
```

**Restart the XAMPP server and run the composer update again.**

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
composer install  --ignore-platform-reqs
```