# Virtual Alloc when composer require of Mavinoo/laravel-batch?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I know this is common issue. But tried some ways on how to fix this but can't do it.

trying to do this

`composer require mavinoo/laravel-batch`

But got an error with `VirtualAlloc()`

What I have tried to modify `php.ini` on my xampp

from this

`memory_limit=128M`

to this

`memory_limit=-1`

Also tried to follow this link too : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/816/how-to-solve-composer-install-update-error-virtualalloc-failed-0x00000008

Seems like that `mavinoo` is too large

[image]

**UDPATE**
[image]

Comment: There are two php.ini for config php. one for config php on apache and another for config php-cli. please sure edited correct php.ini file. please run this command on cmd and see your memory limit. `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"`

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491893/virtualalloc-failed-0x00000008-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-t) and [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/816/how-to-solve-composer-install-update-error-virtualalloc-failed-0x00000008).