# VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] give error in my windows server 2008 R2 and stop my Apache for high request

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using Xampp and Apache in my Windows Server 2008 R2. In normal visitor, my CakePHP 3.5 working perfectly but when real time request increase more then 150, my apache stopped unexpectedly.

Here is my error.log report

```
    VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.
    VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.
```

Is there any solution or i need to take my application in Ubuntu server for re-structure my OS platform. Can anyone give me what can i do now?

Comment: Look at the performance statistics (via Task Manager), my hunch is that your server is out of free memory.  Or your PPHP settings need modifying (see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fatal-php-error-mon-jan-29-233408-2018-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-262144-bytes-in-cxampphtdocssidebarvendorlaravelframeworksrcilluminatecontainercontainerphp-on-line-586-mon-jan-29-233408-2018-php-fa)

Comment: My ram is 32GB and i have trace that my 12GB is using but rest 19GB memory is free. php.ini memory_limit=1024M

Comment: Not much out there, only thing I saw is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103101/wordpress-apache-virtualalloc-and-virtualfree-failed-php-out-of-memory/40033719#40033719